# Why Super() in Python not taking Parent Class Instance variable in Child class

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, object, oop

I am new to OOPs In Python I was trying to access instance variable of a instance method by using Super method "super()" and I was trying it in multiple possibilities but I found out that whenever I am using to access Instance variable I was getting AttributeError

**My Code**

```py
class P:

    def m1(self):

        self.b=10

class C(P):

    def __init__(self):

        super().m1()

        print(super().b)

c=C()

class P:

    a=888

    def m1(self):

        self.a=10
```

**OUTPUT: **

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "D:\myPractice.py\sideRun.py", line 9, in <module>

    c=C()

  File "D:\myPractice.py\sideRun.py", line 7, in __init__

    print(super().b)

AttributeError: 'super' object has no attribute 'b'

-----------------------------------------------------------
```

But whenever I am trying to access Instance variable with self I was getting my desired output.

**My Code**

```py
class C(P):

    def __init__(self):

        super().m1()

        print(super().a)

        print(self.a)
c=C()
```

**OUTPUT**

```
888

10
```

**My Question:**

Why super() method is not enabling internal system to access Instance Variable?

Answer (score -1):

That is because `super().m1()` is the same function as `self.m1()` that means that it sets the attribute `b` to the class C

```py
class P:

    def m1(self):

        self.b=10

class C(P):

    def __init__(self):

        super().m1()

        print(self.b)

c=C()
```

This will print `10`